# My RStudio ggplot2 Histogram Looks Like a Box

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, histogram

I'm new to R (as you can probably tell). My problem is that when I used the following function to make a histogram:

```
fig1 <- ggplot(datos1, aes (x = peso_semilla)) +
  geom_histogram ()
```

R tells me it can't read it because it requires a continuous x aesthetic and the x aesthetic is discrete, so I then added *stat = "count"* to make it continuous:

```
fig11 <- ggplot (datos1, aes (x = peso_semilla)) +
  geom_histogram (stat = "count")
print (fig11)
```

After I do that, R shows me a histogram, but not the one that aligns to the values of my data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7buSr.png)

Other people have done the same and it shows them the right histogram, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I believe it has to do with the fact that my variable "peso_semilla" is read as a discrete value, although it's continuous.
Any help is appreciated ⊂⁠(⁠(⁠・⁠▽⁠・⁠)⁠)⁠⊃

This is an example of what I was expecting to see (it's not done with the same dataset)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcWVF.png)

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(datos1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(datos1, 20))`.

Comment: It's not continuous, it is discrete . Try `aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(peso_semilla)))` and you should get your histogram

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you so much for the help! My mistake was in the dataset. I selected it as a character, after importing the dataset correctly, I didn't have to use stat = "count" anymore. Much appreciated!

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you very much! This made me realize my mistake